# ¿A qué nos referimos con "herramientas de software" en el centro de ayuda?

Tags: discusión, glosario

Debido a un pequeño debate mantenido en los comentarios de [ésta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/45717/hasta-cuando-apple-dar%C3%A1-soporte-a-objective-c) me ha surgido la necesidad de comentarlo por aquí.

Tomando como ejemplo el caso de la pregunta que enlazo… ¿Objective-C no es una herramienta de software? ¿Dónde está el límite acerca de qué se considera como tal y qué no?

Dada esta tesitura, creo que sería interesante definir qué es una "herramienta de software" ya que, en mi humilde opinión, el termino queda algo ambiguo a la vista de los acontecimientos.

¿Cómo lo veis?

Comment: Sugiero agregar la etiqueta [meta-tag:glosario] a esta pregunta.

Comment: Coincido @Rubén, y edité... No me animo a definir la etiqueta, pero sería bueno hacerlo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para definir la línea ente aceptable y no aceptable, yo me plantearía la siguiente pregunta:

> ¿Esta pregunta sobre una herramienta de software va a impactar a la programación en sí?

Si la respuesta es sí, entonces considero que la pregunta entra dentro de lo establecido en el Centro de Ayuda. Si la respuesta es no, entonces considero que la pregunta realmente no es sobre programación en sí, sino sobre un tema tangencial.

**La idea sería ver si la programación y la herramienta de software son el sujeto (o protagonista) de la pregunta, o sólamente un complemento (o actor secundario) de la misma.**

Así, preguntas que serían aceptables:

- ¿Cómo configurar el servidor ABC para poder hacer XYZ?
- ¿A partir de qué versión de la herramienta de software ABC puedo usar el comando XYZ?
- ¿Qué cambios hay de la versión Y.YY a la Z.ZZ del lenguaje/herramienta de software XYZ?

Y otras preguntas que no consideraría aceptables:

- ¿Cuándo se lanzó el IDE para el lenguaje XYZ?
- ¿Debería usar ABC o DEF para desarrollar en XYZ?
- ¿Puedo usar el IDE ABC en la plataforma XYZ?

---

En mi opinión, el problema de la pregunta enlazada es que no es sobre un lenguaje o herramienta de software en sí, sino sobre el soporte que tal o cual compañía va a dar a dicho lenguaje/herramienta de software. Algo que no afecta a la programación en dicho lenguaje.

Podrá influir en mi decisión sobre elegir ese lenguaje u otro diferente, pero no va a cambiar cómo se hace un bucle (sé que es un ejemplo un poco extremo, pero es para ilustrar cómo la pregunta/respuesta no son realmente sobre programación).

Comment: Exactamente como yo lo veo. y tus ejemplos son claros.

Comment: Según entiendo, las preguntas válidas son, aparte de sobre algún tema concreto, las que impacten directamente en la programación en sí misma. ¿Correcto?

Comment: Para mí, sí. Aunque esa relación puede no estar muy clara a veces

Comment: Perfecto pues. Lo tendré en cuenta de aquí en adelante.

Comment: Recuerda que al final lo que importa a la hora de votar es tu propio criterio (tu voto, tu opinión).